# Problems with execute parameters type in MySQLdb

Tags: python, string, execute, mysql-python

```
c.execute("UPDATE Players SET %s = %d WHERE nick=%s",
          (parts[1], int(parts[2]), parts[0]))
```

is giving me the error

```
TypeError: %d format: a number is required, not str
```

I know `execute` should take only `%s`, but `parts[2]` should be cast to int, becacuse it will be an int (inputted as a string).

So, if I put only `%s`'s, of course it comes up with this error:

```
mysql_exceptions.ProgrammingError: (1064,
"You have an error in your SQL syntax; "
"check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version "
"for the right syntax to use near "
"''wins' = '450' WHERE nick='xan'' at line 1")
```

Because `wins` is an integer.
What is the solution to this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I see a couple of problems.
There may be more.

1. You cannot parametrize table nor column names.
   You can, however, do the string substitution and then call `.execute()`.
   If your program takes user input, you'll want to be wary of the potential for [SQL-injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attack.
2. Always use `%s` no matter the type of the parameter.
   MySQLdb handles any quoting that needs to be done.

Example:

```
sql_stmt = "UPDATE Players SET {} = %s WHERE nick=%s;".format(parts[1])
c.execute(sql_stmt, (int(parts[2]), parts[0]))
```

Comment: Thanks bernie, substituting strings and then using execute did the trick.
I'm aware of sql injection, the use of this part of the soft is reserved to admins!